# oracle syntax query

Tags: oracle, syntax, subquery

```
select line_number, times
 FROM LINE
  JOIN LINE_STOP  ON LINE.ID=LINE_STOP.LINE_ID
  JOIN PASSAGE    ON LINE.STOP_ID = PASSAGE.LINE_STOP_ID
where times =
(select count(*) 
from passage
where times between 500 and 620);
```

I am trying to calculate the number of time I have a number between 500 and 620 and sort it by line_number.

It gives me a table with the good column but no value.

these are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Line (
ID              NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
Line_Number     NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
Direction       VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
Day_Week        VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
Stop_ID         NUMBER(5,0) CONSTRAINT Line_Stop_FK REFERENCES Stop);



CREATE TABLE Line_Stop (
ID          NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
Line_ID     NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Line_Stop_Line_FK REFERENCES Line,
Stop_ID     NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Line_Stop_Stop_FK REFERENCES Stop
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE Passage (
ID              NUMBER(5,0) PRIMARY KEY,
Line_Stop_ID    NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Passage_Line_Stop_FK REFERENCES Line_Stop,
Hours           NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
Minutes         NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
Times           Number(4,0) NOT NULL
```

);

Comment: You select the two columns so both of them are empty?

Comment: Yes I get 2 columns but they are empty, so basically I only get a row with Line_number and Times

Comment: What is the result of the subquery? Can execute it separately and then put the result value into where clause, for example, `times = 10`. If it works, then you have a problem in your main query, otherwise, focus on the subquery

Comment: My subquery is working, but not my main query. I've put times=10 but nothing is showing up

Comment: I have no idea why your main query doesn't work because you didn't provide any information about these tables. Probably a problem is in the way you are binding these tables. And you should change the title of your question, because you don't have a problem with the subquery.

Comment: i've edited it so you can see my tables

Comment: you are asking for entries in the passage table where passage.times is equal to the count of all records in the passage table where times are between 500 and 620.  I don't think that is what you want.  so if their are 10 records where time is between 500 and 620 it is looking for an entry where passage.time = 10.   that doesn't make much sense to me.  are you maybe trying to do some kind of group by?

Comment: ohhh ok so how should i write the group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *filters* the *join* having time between `500` and `620`, and then groups it by `line_number` counting the number of occurences

```
select line_number, count(times)
 FROM LINE
  JOIN LINE_STOP  ON (LINE.ID=LINE_STOP.LINE_ID AND LINE.STOP_ID=LINE_STOP.STOP_ID)
  JOIN PASSAGE    ON LINE.STOP_ID = PASSAGE.LINE_STOP_ID
where times between 500 and 620
group by line_number
order by line_number;
```

Comment: I thought it was working but it gives me a too big number for the count(time) line. It gives me 124 when it should be 4.

Comment: @ValérieHallé Try my answer now, added *additional* condition to JOIN..(`AND LINE.STOP_ID=LINE_STOP.STOP_ID`)

Comment: The concept is clear in my query, once you have your JOIN correctly, the result is through.

Comment: Yes it's working!! Thank you very much! It's my first time doing this so it helps a lot! :)